# Moving GIT repository (and commit history) to another repository currently empty

Tags: git

I have a code in a GIT repository `repA` and I need to move it to another repository `repB` that is currently empty but having now the commit and tag history of `repA` in `repB`.

Any advice on the workflow/commands for this process?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The commits *are* the history, so anything that copies the commits, copies the history. The remaining problem is to copy any *names* (branch and/or tag names). Since Git uses the names to *find* the commits, you actually have to solve the second problem first, which then immediately solves the first problem for you. CodeWizard's script will suffice for most users with most repositories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to add new remote and than push your code to the new repo

```
git remote add origin2 <url>
git push origin2 <branch name>
```

Here is a scrip which im using to checkout all branches and than push them to the new remote

```
# first add the new rmeote
git remote add origin2 <new-url>
```

```
#!/bin/bash

# loop over all the original branches
# 1. check them out as local branches 
# 2. set the origin as the track branch
for branch in `git branch -a | grep remotes | grep -v HEAD | grep -v master `; do
    git branch --track ${branch#remotes/origin2/} $branch
done

# now push all branches and tags
git push origin2 --all    
git push origin2 --tags
```

---

#### What does the script do?

**`git branch -a`**
get a list of all the local branches

**`| grep remotes`**
The branch names are : 'remotes/origin/' so this will remove the remotes from the branch names

**`| grep -v HEAD | grep -v master`**
remove the master (current branch) and [HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-back-to-a-previous-location-detached-head/34519716#34519716) which is an alias to the latest commit